# Alternative software to freeping?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there any alternative software to freeping in ubuntu?

```
Note:     
FREEping automatically pings in the background and shows
statistics for each pinged hosts. When a host stops 
responding, FREEping can send popup messages to a 
specified destination.
```

[image: screenshot freeping]

Comment: You could write a shell script that pings the server. If you don't get a response, display a notification! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without parameter, a ping runs forever, but you can restrict it, to wait maximal 10 seconds and do just one ping this way:

```
ping -W10 -c1 askubuntu.com
```

to suppress the output, and issue your warning

```
ping -W10 -c1 askubuntu.com || warning.sh
```

to handle a list of domains

```
urls=(abc.de xy.org jkl.net) 
for url in ${urls[@]} ; 
do 
   ping -W10 -c1 $url || warning.sh
   sleep 10
done
```

To pop up a warning, you need to either start the script by hand, or do some gymnastics with crontab - common errors there: call programs without path. Using x11-programs without specifying the DISPLAY.